# 15.04 Problem: No Nvidia, No Mouse, No Connection

Tags: nvidia, mouse, internet, 15.04

I have upgraded 14.04 to 15.05. After booting, it only opens after I enter as recovery mode and then internet does now work neither my mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with a full re-installation.